# Regarding installing Ubuntu on macbook

Tags: 13.04

I have macbook with OS X 10.6.8, am a student and i want to install Ubuntu on my machine virtually using virtual box i don't have DVD option so want to do it with USB
Can you please help .

Thank you

Vamshi

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use USB to install with Virtual Box.  Download the version of Ubuntu you wish to use (the .iso file) to your hard disk and then mount that file as a virtual CD drive in your Virtual Box VM.  It will then boot from that virtual CD as if it were an actual disc - no CD/DVD drive required - and will guide you through the installation process.

This process is described in the first chapter manual:

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#idp50988256

VirtualBox is pretty nice in that if you name the machine appropriately it will try to guess the OS and architecture you are using.  For example, I usually call mine something like ubuntu-1204-64 (Version 12.04, 64 bit) so I can easily distinguish it from other versions and it will automatically select the correct OS, correct architecture.